# Does the App Store let users download updates not supported by the device OS?

Tags: ios, app-store

I've got a review on the App Store that says that the app hangs on loading after an update I just submitted. I recently stopped supporting iOS 5 in order to use collection views (and because of upcoming iOS 7). Is it possible that this user could have downloaded the update on a device running iOS 5?

Thanks!

Comment: iTunes on a Mac will download the update and Trash the older version, but it won't install the app on a device if the Deployment Target of the app is too high for that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Xcode won't let you run your app on a device running an OS, then the App Store won't allow a user on that OS to update. In fact, I believe that the updates don't even show up for them.

Comment: To clarify: If I set the Deployment Target to 6.0, then users running iOS 5 will NOT be able to download the update. Is that right?

Comment: I certainly believe so.